# mySQL: Joining three tables - how?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have the following query in my application. It works well, but I need it to also contain the number of products that are associated with each manufacturer.

The current query:

```
SELECT * FROM (`manufacturers`)
JOIN `languages` ON `manufacturers`.`lang` = `languages`.`id`
ORDER BY `languages`.`id` asc, `id` asc
```

My products table looks like this:

```
id    |    name    |    manufacturerid
0     |   Product1 |    0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT `manufacturers`.*, `languages`.*, COUNT(`products`.`id`) AS NumberOfProducts
FROM (`manufacturers`)
JOIN `languages` ON `manufacturers`.`lang` = `languages`.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `products` ON 
      `products`.`manufacturerid` =  `manufacturers`.`manufacturerid`
GROUP BY <Column list for manufacturers AND languages here>
ORDER BY `languages`.`id` asc, `manufacturers`.`id` asc
```

Comment: I was far too slow off the mark on this one but another option!

Comment: Hi Martin, can you explain "<Column list for manufacturers AND languages here>" ?

Comment: @Industrial As you only had `*` in your select I wasn't able to know what they are. Anything in the SELECT list that is not an aggregate or literal should be in the `GROUP BY` clause. I think MySQL allows them not to be but that would change the semantics of the query.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * 
from `manufacturers` m
inner join `languages` l on m.`lang` = l.`id` 
left outer join (
    select manufacturerid, count(*) as ProductCount
    from Products
    group by manufacturerid
) pc on m.id = pc.manufacturerid
order by l.`id` asc, m.`id` asc
```

Comment: Hi! I get the following error when using your solution: 
Error Number: 1096 No tables used SELECT * ORDER BY `languages`.`id` asc, `manufacturerid` asc

Comment: Never mind OrbMan, I had a query that run directly after this that caused the error. Sorry, and thanks a lot for your help!