# How to join three tables in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have following tables.I need to join the vehicle details with vehicle option.One vehicle may have more than one options like Anti Theft,Leather Interior etc.I tried the left join.But not getting the exact result.

`My question`: Is there any way to get only one row whether the options have one or many?Means the options need to get the form of array or something.

```
**vehicle_det**

vdId | Mileage | Transmission | IntColour | selCategory | price | selDriveTrain | Fuel  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


**vehicle_option_trans**

id | vehicleId | optionId
------------------------


**vehicle_options**

id | type
---------
```

Query Schema -

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle_det 
    (
     vdId  int auto_increment primary key, 
     Mileage  varchar(20), 
     Transmission  varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO vehicle_det
(Mileage, Transmission)
VALUES
('10', 'automatic'),
('12', 'automatic'),
('5', 'manual'),
('11', 'manual');  


CREATE TABLE vehicle_option_trans 
    (
     id  int auto_increment primary key, 
     vehicleId  varchar(20), 
     optionId  varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO vehicle_option_trans
(vehicleId, optionId)
VALUES
('1', '1'),
('1', '3'),
('1', '4'),
('2', '2');   


CREATE TABLE vehicle_options 
    (
     id  int auto_increment primary key, 
     type  varchar(20)    );

INSERT INTO vehicle_options
(type)
VALUES
('Power Roof'),
('Sun Roof'),
('Heated Mirrors'),
('Alloy Wheels');
```

**[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95e0e)**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: give us the code you have tried so we can try fixing it.

Comment: what query have you tried ?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984844/mysql-joining-three-tables-how?rq=1

Comment: SELECT * FROM vehicle_option_trans LEFT JOIN vehicle_det ON vehicle_det.vdId = vehicle_option_trans.vehicleId 
LEFT JOIN vehicle_options ON vehicle_options.id = vehicle_option_trans.optionId WHERE vehicleId = 12

This is the one query i tried

Comment: Can you show the desired output result sample

Comment: Lets create the tables in sqlfiddle Deonia.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95e0e Please check this

Comment: @ThomasTkr use the `edit` link under your question and update it with the query you have tried (which you answered in the comments).

Comment: @Burhan Khalid  I just update it with sqlfiddle.Am sure that left join will mislead the other people.Thats why i didnt include it in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return only one row per vehicle, with all of its options, you need to do a [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat. This will return a comma separated array -

```
SELECT
    vehicle_det.*, GROUP_CONCAT(vehicle_options.type) as options
FROM 
    vehicle_det  
LEFT JOIN 
    vehicle_option_trans 
ON
    vehicle_det.vdId = vehicle_option_trans.vehicleId 
LEFT JOIN
    vehicle_options 
ON
    vehicle_options.id = vehicle_option_trans.optionId
GROUP BY vehicle_det.vdId
```

using your sqlfiddle data, this returns

[image]

see this sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/290c4a/9

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select veh.*,group_concat(opt.type) as type from vehicle_det as veh
left join vehicle_option_trans as trans on
trans.vehicleId = veh.vdID left join vehicle_options
as opt on opt.id= trans.optionId where veh.vdID = '1'
```